# SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling, securityexception

How do I solve this error? I tried:

1. Refreshing the project, and rebuilding.
2. Cleaning the project, and rebuilding.
3. Closing and reopening the project, and rebuilding
4. Deleting the project (but not deleting the files — that's a
   checkbox on the project deletion confirmation dialog), and re-
   importing it as an existing project, and cleaning and rebuilding.
5. Deleting the project, deleting the `.project` and `.classpath` files in the
   project, and creating a new project using my files as existing
   sources.

None of these worked. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not roll back helpful edits.

Comment: i dont think so.Your edits isnt helpful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

update platform sdk version to rev 21 it can be solved.
I updated platform SDK from rev 20  to rev 21, and restart eclipse, it's solved.

Comment: If you don't see rev21 available in SDK manager, go to Tools->Options and clear the cache, then reload.

Comment: On Mac OSX, run SDK Manager, then click from the top Menu 'Android SDK Manager / Preferences / Manifest Cache'. Then choose top menu 'Packages / Reload'.

Answer (score 2):

Did this happen after you updated the Android-SDK or something like that? Have you tried to uninstall it and install again?

I just had the same problem and the only solution I found was:
- Uninstall Android SDK (as plugin in Eclipse as well and delete manually any related file you can find in the Eclipse directory)
- Get the newest Android-SDK
- Install it again

I hope it helps in your case too!

Comment: yes it happen after the update the android-sdk. Ok ı try that i hope it figure out.

Comment: now ı finished update after uninstallation then it is fixed.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: "any related file you can find in the Eclipse directory" <- could someone elaborate on this? :C

Comment: @yoshi: By that I meant actually "any file related to the Android-SDK which you can still find in the Eclipse directory (after having uninstalling it)". I hope this helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This error may stem from a faulty batch file in android sdk.

The following fixed worked for me

1. Open the file `find_java.bat` found in `android-sdk\tools\lib`
2. Find the line `for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a`
3. Remove *"-s"*; `for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a`
4. Save the file, and restart eclipse.